# Ajax cannot reach the post page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been spending hours trying to figure out what is wrong with this code, i found out that i cannot reach the updateuser.php file, its on the same directory, the filenames are corret, is there something wrong with this code:

```
<script>
 function updateuseracc(form, password)
{   
var p = document.createElement("input");

form.appendChild(p);
p.name="p";
p.type="hidden";
p.value=hex_sha512(password.value);
password.value="";

var useremail=$("#curemail").val();


$.post('updateuser.php',{email:useremail,p:p}).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
    });


}
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in Firefox, with the Firebug extension installed and activated? That ought to show you both Javascript errors and hassles, and network problems.

Comment: Are you including this script from somewhere else? Is another page in another directory actually loading this script? Also, you don't need `.done` at the end of your `$.post`.  Just remove `).done(` and replace it with `, `

Comment: You also might want to use absolute path with $.ajax functions.

Comment: we are to assume that you are calling the `updateuseracc()` with `onSubmit` or `onClick` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Bring up development tools with F12 on Google Chrome, then go to 'Network' option and check if after calling the script a 500 header page is returned. You can check this at the list of resources called that you will see at development bar.

If so, you will know that you are not referring to the script correctly, also you will get information from the parsed URL so you can guess how can you set the path to updateuser.php.